# Network Drive not Shown

Tags: windows, networking

I have one computer which does not show one of my network drives . I have to reboot it or use the command gpupdate/force . Any idea why this is happening . 
Regards

Comment: Are you able to ping the server from that computer? Have you tried mapping it to a different drive letter in case of conflict?

Answer (score 0):

Is your network Drive apart of your domain?

if it isn't then you will have issues with the drive staying mapped, and issue with permissions as well.

You can setup a log on script to run at startup that will automatically map you network drive.

> @echo off
>
> net use * /delete /y
>
> net use i: \"IP ADDRES"\"SHARENAME" /USER:"DOMAIN"\"USERNAME" "PASSWORD"
>   /PERSISTENT:YES

Simply create a Batch script with the above code replacing everything in quotes with your file server details and save it in your "startup" folder

If your file server is apart of your domain then it could be a network issue, sometimes the computer will boot up into the OS before connecting to the network, forgetting about GPO's etc..

Fast-boot is a feature in windows 8 and 10 i don't know what OS you are using so this could be the issue.

How to turn it off.
http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html